# Why doesn't mongoexport generate the output file

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoexport

I have a `Mongo` database on my server and I can connect to it using `docker`.
I run the following command:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongoexport --port 27017 -u "username" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" -d databaseName -c user --out /var/www/myTest/output.json
```

It seems that the command works without any problem and I get the message:

```
connected to: mongodb://localhost:27017/
exported 16 records
```

However, when I use FileZilla and look at the directory `/var/www/myTest`, there is no file there. The folder is empty (I had created the folder myself earlier. If I use a new folder name, the folder is also not generated).

What have I done wrong? Is the file somewhere else?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In case anyone else needs it, I used this command to copy the file I had created to somewhere outside of the container:
docker cp mongodb:/var/www/myTest/output.json /var/www/myTest

Comment: you can also bind mount a dir from host, see my update in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That directory and the file is inside the mongoexport container.

**UPDATE:**

You could also bind mount a directory from your host to the containers:

`docker run --rm -v /var/www/myTestOnHost:/var/www/myTestOnContainer -it mongodb mongoexport --port 27017 -u "username" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" -d databaseName -c user --out /var/www/myTestOnContainer/output.json`

docs: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

`--rm` flag for `docker run` will remove the container when it finished running, that is executing the `mongoexport --port 27017 -u "username" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" -d databaseName -c user --out /var/www/myTestOnContainer/output.json` command